# Rendered Scene Looks Incorrect/Weird

Tags: rendering

Doing a render of this view[image]

Results in this output which looks strange, is there anything obvious I've messed up here ? Lighting, Cameras ? I have a single camera that I'm using (Use local camera is not ticked)

[image]

Comment: The stripes on the materials looks like you have flat planes lying on top each other so they are intersecting. Are they all at the same level?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a light and images appear pink with moved texture try to add a color to the objects and a base .

Answer (score 0):

The top image is not the camera view but a view from the 3d vieport. The second one is the camera view.

The camera is slightly rotated on the X axis. To get the camera to look straight down you can clear the rotation by selecting the camera and pressingg <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

To get an image without any perspective distortion use an orthogonal camera.